# File Manager PCManFM not the one as shown in USC

Tags: pcmanfm

I've installed Ubuntu 13.10, and also installed PCManFM from USC, but when I launched it, it didn't work as indicated in [this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/pcmanfm/) page.

It works more like Files. Is it possible someone put in a wrong one in the USC ?

And when I search  in Dashboard, the filtered result shows PCManFM and Desktop Preference, not that I expect PCManFM and Files.

Comment: Looks like the right thing to me. It's in the Ubuntu archives, not a special release through USC. Perhaps the features/design in the new version are just not what you expected, and maybe don't match the older screen shot exactly?

Comment: I'm new to askubuntu, I can't post image for now... I believe they post a wrong app. under PCManFM name.

Comment: Definitely it is not the wrong app. Though may you are not running it properly, and instead are running nautilus, which is installed by default.

Comment: Too bad I can't post the picture, the app. is not the one shown in USC, no menu bar, no thumbnail, even less functionality than nautilus. Not sure what you mean "are not running it properly", I just simply installed the app. in USC and launched it from dashboard.

Comment: one thing I don't understand is why all applications I start don't have menu bar, where can I find the Help>About information ?

Comment: @Jack you can tell us the link to the picture, I think, and we can edit it in (we being the users who can actually edit).  Assuming you actually upload a screenshot of what you see to somewhere

Comment: Thanks Tom, I've found my problem. I'm new to Ubuntu and its Unity stuff. I didn't know all apps' menu are not with the apps now, they all go to the top!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I know what the problem was.

I was expecting the File (etc) menu to be on the application but it was actually at the top of the screen.